# Could life form in a universe without galaxies?

Tags: science-based, space, physics

Galaxies, they come in many shapes, and many sizes. In fact, the universe is filled with galaxies, holding the stars and planets together. What if, in a universe where black holes and dark matter don't exist, would habitable planets form? Would there be intelligent life?

Comment: how old is your universe and does it use similar set of fundamental physical constants as ours?

Comment: @user6760 just as old as our universe. the same physical constants as ours, however dark matter doesn't exist and black holes cannot form by any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Doubtful, but maybe.**

The elements for life (Carbon, oxygen, nitrogen, etc) come from nuclear fusion within stars. When stars go supernova, they release enormous amounts of matter and dust that's to be recycled into new stars and planets. If stars were not bound to each other in a galaxy, then there is a lot less chance for a sufficiently rocky and element-filled planet to form.

You could expect rogue stars and their own planetary systems, perhaps. What happens when the rogue star dies? The planetary system has no heat and it will fly as a celestial corpse through the universe with no hope of ever being revived.

And how would they come about? They'd have to be formed from whatever was available when the universe was smaller, and we have another issue that makes that still more difficult.

*The lack of dark matter.*

Matter from supernovae are ejected with so much speed and force that without dark matter it would fly off into the void without the extra gravity to make sure it forms into new stars or accretion disks. You couldn't expect rocky planets to form.

Structure in the early universe was predicated upon gravity, dark matter, and larger densities. Your question does not preclude dark energy, so we still have the forced expansion of the universe.

The universe I see under your constraints is a desolate one. What few planetary systems that could have formed with enough material and elements for life would be long dead now.

**However** there is a chance that the early universe had just the right setting for life, beforehand.